# How to extract items from json objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

This is the json object I get after running a script.

```
{
    "log": {
        "entries": [{
                "startedDateTime": "2015-08-16T10:27:35.264Z",
                "time": 35,
                "request": {
                    "method": "GET",
                    "url": "http://www.google.com/",
                    "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
                    "cookies": [],
                    "headers": [{
                        "name": "User-Agent",
                        "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.8 Safari/534.34"
                    }, {
                        "name": "Accept",
                        "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
                    }],
                    "queryString": [],
                    "headersSize": -1,
                    "bodySize": -1
                },
                "response": {
                    "status": 302,
                    "statusText": "Found",
                    "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
                    "cookies": [],
                    "headers": [{
                        "name": "Cache-Control",
                        "value": "private"
                    }, {
                        "name": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
                    }, {
                        "name": "Location",
                        "value": "http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=mWXQVZiNLaHv8wehp6jYDw"
                    }, {
                        "name": "Content-Length",
                        "value": "261"
                    }, {
                        "name": "Date",
                        "value": "Sun, 16 Aug 2015 10:27:37 GMT"
                    }, {
                        "name": "Server",
                        "value": "GFE/2.0"
                    }, {
                        "name": "Connection",
                        "value": "keep-alive"
                    }],
                    "redirectURL": "",
                    "headersSize": -1,
                    "bodySize": 261,
                    "content": {
                        "size": 261,
                        "mimeType": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
                    }
                },
                "cache": {},
                "timings": {
                    "blocked": 0,
                    "dns": -1,
                    "connect": -1,
                    "send": 0,
                    "wait": 35,
                    "receive": 0,
                    "ssl": -1
                },
                "pageref": "http://www.google.com"
            }, .....
        ]
    }
}
```

In my javascript, I am trying to access every object. But its not working.

Lets say for example, I assign this json object to data:

```
data = JSON.parse({... that whole json object...});
console.log(data["log"]["entries"][0]);
```

I get nothing. I am using this inside node. What mistake am I doing here ?

Comment: do you get nothing or something like `[Object object]`?

Comment: Put the output of `console.log(data)`

Comment: There is nothing like "nothing" in JavaScript. either you will see your data or undefined. Please specify clearly what you get

Comment: JSON.parse() expects a string to be parsed to a json-object. It sounds like you already have an object, dont you? In that case you do not need to parse it again.

Comment: "JSON object" is an oxymoron. JSON is a data serialization format. Either you have JSON (i.e. a string in a certain format), or you have an object.

Comment: I get nothing. When i am running node server, i get nothing in console nor in web page. i am really confused what did i do wrong... !

Comment: @Bala as @nils mentioned it `JSON.parse()` expects a string to be parsed not a object so instead of parsing it directly access the element you want

Comment: Its a string, I use Stringfy() and then use parse.

Comment: It doesn't look like a string from what you've posted. It is already an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should treat this as object, here is a working fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/8jqvvmc6/3/

```
var jsonData = {
    "log": {
        "entries": [{
            "startedDateTime": "2015-08-16T10:27:35.264Z",
                "time": 35,
                "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                    "url": "http://www.google.com/",
                    "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
                    "cookies": [],
                    "headers": [{
                    "name": "User-Agent",
                        "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/1.9.8 Safari/534.34"
                }, {
                    "name": "Accept",
                        "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
                }],
                    "queryString": [],
                    "headersSize": -1,
                    "bodySize": -1
            },
                "response": {
                "status": 302,
                    "statusText": "Found",
                    "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
                    "cookies": [],
                    "headers": [{
                    "name": "Cache-Control",
                        "value": "private"
                }, {
                    "name": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
                }, {
                    "name": "Location",
                        "value": "http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=mWXQVZiNLaHv8wehp6jYDw"
                }, {
                    "name": "Content-Length",
                        "value": "261"
                }, {
                    "name": "Date",
                        "value": "Sun, 16 Aug 2015 10:27:37 GMT"
                }, {
                    "name": "Server",
                        "value": "GFE/2.0"
                }, {
                    "name": "Connection",
                        "value": "keep-alive"
                }],
                    "redirectURL": "",
                    "headersSize": -1,
                    "bodySize": 261,
                    "content": {
                    "size": 261,
                        "mimeType": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
                }
            },
                "cache": {},
                "timings": {
                "blocked": 0,
                    "dns": -1,
                    "connect": -1,
                    "send": 0,
                    "wait": 35,
                    "receive": 0,
                    "ssl": -1
            },
                "pageref": "http://www.google.com"
        }]
    }
};
alert(jsonData["log"]["entries"][0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7amzq8wj/) to see how it should work in your case. Also I assume `data` should be a local variable, it might get overwritten somewhere before your code executes. Don't pollute the global scope I guess.

Answer (score 0):

That does not work!

```
data = JSON.parse({... that whole json object...});
```

because

```
data = {... that whole json object...};
```

is already an object.

But if you have

```
data = JSON.parse('{... that whole json object...}');
```

then it should be parsed first, to convert a string to an JSON compliant object.